# Should we avoid JFXPanel recreation, when Platform.setImplicitExit(false), to avoid JavaFX resource leakage

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Currently, I'm integrating JavaFX into Swing.

I need to use `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`, due to [JavaFX IllegalStateException when disposing JFXPanel in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867120/javafx-illegalstateexception-when-disposing-jfxpanel-in-swing)

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    }
}
```

I was wondering, should I avoid recreating `JFXPanel` then, every-times I want to show the `JDialog` which owns the `JFXPanel`? To avoid possible JavaFX resource leakage, should I use

```
public class SimpleSwingBrowser extends JDialog { 
    // Avoid JFXPanel re-creation.
    private static final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
}
```

or

```
public class SimpleSwingBrowser extends JDialog { 
    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very good question - the interaction between JFX application thread and Swing is messy, to say the least.